# Repeat Question in Pagination

Tags: support, bug

From time to time, I do scroll through unanswered questions in SO to search for questions that I could offer to help and answer. Sometime the same question would pop up again in later scrolling, I thought it was just my imagination. Until this afternoon, I found myself comparing two questions in same pagination, and I took a screenshot to illustrate my concern.

Is this expected behavior, a bug, or there are really two same questions with identical values?

[image]

Comment: Probably an SQL mistake? Anyway, definitely not 2 identical questions because I think that questions are automatically blocked if they have the same title as another question to stop double posting.

Comment: @StephenLeppik search results come out of Elastic. It could be that it incorrectly got indexed twice.

Comment: It doesn't return the issue when searching for it...

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior with the CSS tag in Unanswered Questions under [No Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/css?tab=noanswers). [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGK2S.png). The duplicate listing continues to persist after several minutes, despite refreshing.